# 301 redirects on Zeus web server

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, zeus

Unfortunately one of my clients uses Zeus web server at the hosting company he uses.  I have never used it before.

I need to set up simple 301 redirects but Zeus does not use .htaccess, it uses its own file rewrite.script

Does anyone know how to do a basic 301 redirect using rewrite.script for Zeus?  the equivalent of:

redirect 301 /pagename http://domain.com/newpage.php

in .htaccess.

The actual file names have changed too so I can't just do a straight redirect of the whole domain, I need to set up individual 301 redirects for all of the 20 pages.

I've tried the suggestion posted below by someone here on stackoverflow, as well as this which I found on another website, and it's all being ignored.  Does the host need to enable something?  I know the rewrite.script is being read because Im using it for search engine friendly URL's.

```
#— 301 Redirect —

match URL into $ with ^/old.html$
if matched
set OUT:Location = http://www.yourdomain.co.uk/new.html
set OUT:Content-Type = text/html
set RESPONSE = 301
set BODY = Moved
goto END
endif
```

Here is my entire rewrite.script

```
#Zeus webserver version of basic WordPress mod_rewrite rules
map path into SCRATCH:path from %{URL}
look for file at %{SCRATCH:path}
if exists then goto END
look for dir at %{SCRATCH:path}
if exists then goto END
##### FIX FOR LOGIN/FORGOTTEN PASSWORD/ADMIN ETC #####
match URL into $ with ^/wp-.*$
if matched then goto END
##### FIX TO ALLOW SEARCH TO WORK #####
match URL into $ with ^/(.*)
set URL = /$1

RULE_0_START:
match URL into $ with ^\/pagename$
if not matched then goto RULE_1_END
if matched then
    set URL = http://domain.com/newpage.php
    set RESPONSE = 301
    set OUT:Location = %{URL}
    set BODY = Please try <a href="%{URL}">here</a> instead\n
goto END
RULE_0_END:
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this (once for each redirect)?

```
RULE_0_START:
match URL into $ with ^\/pagename$
if not matched then goto RULE_1_END
if matched then
    set URL = http://domain.com/newpage.php
    set RESPONSE = 301
    set OUT:Location = %{URL}
    set BODY = Please try <a href="%{URL}">here</a> instead\n
goto END
RULE_0_END:
```

You have to increase the rule number by one for each rule.

Comment: Thanks.  So would I replace /pagename$ with the old page such as /page?52$

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but unfortunately the rule is being ignored.  Why on earth are these people using Zeus.. it's driving me insane.

Comment: I checked and don't see any other rules.  I'll post my entire rewrite.script so you can see what it looks like.  I also tried changing the line: if not matched then goto RULE_1_END to RULE_0_END in case it was a typo.. neither works.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use this - it makes it much easier...

http://seo-website-designer.com/Zeus-Server-301-Redirect-Generator

Answer (score 0):

Zeus supports .htaccess and many of its directives, including Redirect.  See page 325 onward here:

http://support.zeus.com/ZWSUserGuide.pdf

The link relates to version 4.3.  I'm not sure about earlier versions.